# Permission Set deploy error - no custom field named XXX.yyy found

Tags: deployment, custom-field, permission-sets

Use case is deploying from GitHub to a CI org. Deployment includes a `PermissionSet`

- Salesforce reports error on `PermissionSet Foo`:

  ```
  In field: field - no CustomField named OrderItem.MyField__c found
  ```
- But, if I look in GitHub, there is no reference at all in any file to `OrderItem.MyField__c`. *No reference at all!*
- If I look in the target org in object `OrderItem`, there is no `MyField__c`

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the target org did have a reference to `OrderItem.MyField__c`.

- It was a deleted field, not yet erased

So, I erased the field and reran the deploy

- Same error ?!?

I waited a couple of minutes thinking that the hard delete of the field might take some time to propagate to the `PermissionSet Foo` - though the [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_purge_deleted_fields.htm&type=5) says the hard delete effect occurs within 30 secs if you don't receive an email (and I did not)

- I reran the deploy 5 minutes later, same error ?!?

So, I ended up going to the `Permission Set Foo`, Object Settings for `OrderItem` and clicked `Edit-made no changes-Save`

- I reran the deploy and it worked

I can't explain this and it is of course possible that the hard delete process in the target org took 20+ minutes and my last step was superfluous. Or, perhaps there's something weird about `OrderItem` and how SFDC cleans out PermissionSets on field deletion.